# Serial Port over the Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, serial-port

I am starting to program in C# and build applications over the web.
I have a board with a PIC microcontroller that I made that communicates with the PC via USB-Serial converter (FT232). 
Now I want to do this: I want to create a website on another computer that allows you to communicate with the PC with the PIC board. Via the other computer I want to be able to control the PIC board. 
I think that in order to do that I have to start learning about ActiveX, if I'm not mistaken. Does ActiveX allow me to write on another computer's serial port?
I really want to learn that. 
Could you please guide me in the correct direction, and if possible a book or tutorial?
Thank you very much, and sorry for any english mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ActiveX is to let a web page interact with the computer of the visitor of that web page, an old system which should not be used again. Although HTML5 seems to want to reimplement a lot of ActiveX-like functionality again, this is not what you want.

If you create a C# application or service that uses the [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class to talk to your PIC, and use for example a WCF service to accept commands over the internet.

You can then create a web page that lets the user issue commands, while the back end of the web page calls the WCF service to send the command to the PIC.

Comment: yes, except that part about HTML5 reimplementing ActiveX.  That's not true.

Comment: @MK. The good ol' ActiveX did for example let you access multimedia devices and sockets, and gave you a scripting language. HTML5 strives to do the same. Although it was just a sidenote. :-)

Comment: ActiveX allowed you to do *anything*.  HTML5, hopefully, won't.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. In order to access the serial port remotely, from the server to the client, I need to have an application alerady installed on the client computer? Sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm a newbie.

Comment: @user1053944 No. The WCF service will run on the server #1 that's connected to the PIC. Your website runs on server #2, and accesses server #1 through WCF. Your client then simply visits the website on server #2, and does its thing. Server #2 will then issue the request on server #1.

Answer (score 2):

You could build a **website or a webservice which runs on the computer with the PIC board**. This website would allow you to send commands to the local attached board.

If you have got a .NET SDK for your board you should be able to wrap all the commands in the service or website.

Comment: I have already tried that and I have already been successfull at it, now I wanted to do the opposite. My objective here is to learn C#. That's why I wanted to access another PC's serial port via a website hosted on another computer.

Comment: But thank you for your answer. I'm really impressed with this place. I put a question about an hour ago, went to lunch and when I was back I already had 2 2 answers, and 3 more comments on answers. You're all really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Might look at something like this product http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/serial-over-ethernet/, if you want to make it look like a local serial port.  If that's not necessary, I'd write a service that listened on a socket and simply sent the serial data between the socket and the serial port.